# Jenkins not accessible through LAN

Tags: networking, jenkins

I've installed Jenkins through brew, and it is now running on port 8080 on `Machine A` (with IP `10.0.6.6`): `10.0.6.6:8080` gives me Jenkins when on `Machine A`.

On Machine B, if I type in `10.0.6.6:8080`, the page does not load. I've ensured that port `8080` is indeed open, and I've opened it manually with:

```
sudo ipfw add 8080 allow tcp from any to any dst-port 8080
```

I have Apache running and listening on port `80` on `Machine A`, and I can access that just fine from Machine B with `10.0.6.6:80`

Running `sudo lsof -i:8080` to see what's listening on port 8080 gives:

```
java      67405            root  168u  IPv6 0x8559ae29226e47f7      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt (LISTEN)
java      67405            root  276u  IPv6 0x8559ae2927c6b397      0t0  TCP localhost:http-alt->localhost:52067 (ESTABLISHED)
```

`Machine A` is on Mac OSX 10.8.5. Any idea what could be causing this?

Any additional details I can give:

I installed Jenkins with:

```
brew install jenkins
```

I start Jenkins with:

```
sudo launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
```

Answer (score 14):

The default homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist from homebrew has the following:

```
<string>--httpListenAddress=127.0.0.1</string>
```

This makes it listen only on localhost.  To make it listen on all interfaces you can replace that with:

```
<string>--httpListenAddress=0.0.0.0</string>
```

Then I think you need to launchctl unload/load to restart.  You could also put a more specific listen address if you want, of course.

Comment: Some extra info:

The file lives in /usr/local/Cellar/jenkins/X.YZ/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist -- also, you can start stop homebrew jenkins with `brew services stop jenkins` and `brew services start jenkins`

Answer (score 1):

In 2021 on an M1 mac running BigSur the **Homebrew** plist file is actually located at `/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins/2.290/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

you will need to:
`sudo YOUR_FAV_EDITOR /opt/homebrew/Cellar/jenkins/2.290/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist`

and change the `--httpListenAddress` as noted above (in John Evanson's answer) for all interfaces (0.0.0.0) to use `brew services start jenkins` / `brew services stop jenkins` / `brew services restart jenkins`

Hopefully, this updated information helps someone :)

Answer (score 0):

go to

```
~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist
```

and Change the `httpListenAddress` value from `127.0.0.1` to `0.0.0.0`

Since this homebrew.mxcl.jenkins.plist file in placed in LaunchAgents you need to restart your machine to make this effective.